# 'Error converting data type nvarchar to int' when passing multiple INT parameters in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, type-conversion

I have a simply report and would like to pass multiple INT value parameter (Product ID 'int') when I am running the report. When I choose the single value (Product ID), it runs well. But when I choose more than one value, in the report preview, it shows 'Error converting data type nvarchar to int' .

Does anyone have any idea about fixing this 'simple' problem? I think maybe i need to convert the parameter in SP. But I tried 2 days and got nothing.

Realllllly Appreciate It!!

(I am using SQL SERVER 2008.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you might need to convert your parameter's data type to varchar and use that as IN query as Product ID like

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductID IN (@ProductIDs)
```

where @ProductIds will be varchar.